# how to read a datalabel's text in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to read in a given datalabel's text.

What I have tried:

```
print(plot.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.text)
```

Snippet above tries to print the 1st series' first point which is '16' but it prints nothing.

[image]

How can I obtain what is in the datalabel?

I want to read the text in, concat something new to it and reinsert it into the data label. Something like this

```
dltext = plot.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.text
plot.series[0].points[0].data_label.text_frame.text = dltext + "Foo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data_label.text_frame` only contains text if you put it there explicitly. Otherwise what is rendered is a function of the value of that data-point and the settings `.show_value` and `show_percent`, etc. documented here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.datalabel.DataLabels

If you want to match what shows to the user you'll need to duplicate that logic.

If you wanted to accomplish that for the general case, it would take some doing because you'd need to compute the *effective* value of properties like `DataLabel.show_value`, which would require reverse-engineering the style hierarchy for that setting.

But the 95% solution would just be to assume what is showing is the value and go with that. That's the default data label, at least for bar charts (pie charts may default to percent).